# Generic solution to check if all inputs are valid inside a fieldset, if so enable button

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, loops

I would like to check if all inputs inside a fieldset has class 'valid'. If so, enable the submit button

```
<form>
// This fieldset will have a classname "valid" when the image suits the requirements
<fieldset id="fieldset-large" class="ssa-fieldset">
    <input type="file"> 
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="fieldset-small" class="ssa-fieldset">
    <input type="file"> 
</fieldset>

... more fieldsets coming ...

<button type="submit">Next step</button>
</form>
```

The behaviour I am aiming is:

```
if ($('#fieldset-large').hasClass('valid') && $('#fieldset-small').hasClass('valid')) {
    FORM_SUBMIT_BUTTON.removeAttr('disabled');
} else {
    FORM_SUBMIT_BUTTON.attr('disabled','disabled');
}
```

How do I make this more generic?

Comment: how are you appending valid class and on what event you are checking this

Comment: all fieldset needs to have classname 'valid'. Already have a method to check the inputs. I want, if ALL fieldsets inside form, each of them hasClass 'valid', enable button.

Comment: The validation of input file is great (only accept image, exact dimension, min filesize, etc), behaves as I want it.. and when the image is valid - classname 'valid' will be added on image onload.

Comment: `I would like to check if all inputs inside a fieldset has class 'valid'` Inside each fieldset independently or inside the whole `form`??? I guess the whole `form` because your `form` has only one submit button defined

Comment: @ivanasetiawan : did you try my answer?

Comment: @YoYo: Will do tmrw.. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find `.ssa-fieldset` inside the form. Then for each result check if has the class `valid`. If some of the input don't have it define a new var `isValid` as false and break the loop. After that just check the value of `isValid` and enable or disable the submit button.

```
var isValid = false; 
$('form').find('.ssa-fieldset').each(function(){
    if(this).hasClass('valid'){
        isValid = true;
    }else{
        isValid = false;
        break;
    }
}
if(isValid === true){           
    $('input[type="submit"]').removeProp('disabled');
}else{
    $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean for all input, then use this instead :

```
var fieldSet = $('.ssa-fieldset').length;
var a = $('.ssa-fieldset :input.valid').length;

if ( a === fieldset ) {
    FORM_SUBMIT_BUTTON.removeAttr('disabled');
}
else {
   FORM_SUBMIT_BUTTON.attr('disabled','disabled');
}
```

This code depend on fieldset you have and only single element are existed only inside

Answer (score 0):

If a `valid`class is added, you could use:

```
$('form').on('change', function(){ // change event or input event
    var $inputs = $(this).find(':input:not(:submit)'); // get all form inputs except the submit one(s)
    $(this).find(':submit').prop('disabled', $inputs.length !== $inputs.filter('.valid').length); // check all have class valid
}).change(); //trigger change event once bound
```

Otherwise, the API's way would be to use `pattern(?)/required` attribute(s) and check for `form` validity using `form.checkValidity()`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var valid = false;
$("fieldset input").each(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("valid")) valid = false;
    else valid = true
});
valid == false ? $("button").attr("disabled", "disabled") : $("button").removeAttr("disabled")
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/pmadwvpk/5/

Answer (score 0):

select all `fieldset` and Loop in

```
$('form > fieldset').each(function(){
    if ($(this).find("input").hasClass('valid')) {
        FORM_SUBMIT_BUTTON.removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        FORM_SUBMIT_BUTTON.attr('disabled','disabled');
         return false;
    }

    });
```

Comment: keep in mind ***I would like to check if all inputs inside a fieldset has class 'valid'. If so, enable the submit button***

Comment: @guradio : ohh i did not notice that,, edited  thanks

Comment: Sorry my bad i missed that :)

Answer (score 0):

In your **add fieldset** js function (if you intend to have such functionality), manually trigger `$('form').change();`

```
$('form').on('change',function(){
    // get fieldset element count
    var fcnt = $(this).find('fieldset').length;
    // get fieldset element count having a "valid" class
    var vcnt = $(this).find('fieldset[class*="valid"]').length;

    if(fcnt == vcnt)
        $(this).find('button[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    else
        $(this).find('button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
});

// to manually trigger form change
$('form').change();
```